# I want my text to wait for a user to click

Tags: python, user-input, replit

I am a beginner to Python and am having trouble with getting text to wait until the user clicks their mouse. How can I do so? what I want to do is I want to print("text") have it wait till the user clicks and then print("more text"), if that makes sense
so for example:

```
print("More text will be printed when user clicks")

CODE THAT DETECTS USER CLICKING/WAITS FOR USER INPUT

print("More text")
```

I tried using time.sleep(0) thinking it would just wait for a user input.
I also tried using input() but it didnt work it said somthing about 2 arguments when one was expected
I am using Replit to host my code
I do not want to use tkinter

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it using input as

```
print("justsometext")
i=input("click enter")
print("evenmoretext")
```

instead of what i did earlier which was wrong

```
i=input("justsometext,click enter for more")
print("evenmoretext")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install mouse
```

and then try the following :

```py
import mouse

print("More text will be printed when the user clicks")


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        print("More text")

mouse.on_click(on_click)

input("Click anywhere to exit.")
```